# Two labels having first line in alignment

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have two labels placed horizontally. One is multiple line and other is having only one line. I want to display their first line should be in one line. E.g. label1= "stackoverflow community helpers"
Label2 = "User" then stackoverflow word and user word should be in one lone.

Any help?

Comment: Add your code please.

Comment: Can you share your code and also provide an example of how you want things to look like?

Comment: I will post code in some time but basically i want to have first line of two labels horizontally aligned. My two labels have same height and y position.

Comment: You probably want a UIStackView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First approach ->
Use constraints give both labels the left, right, and top constraints only do not give bottom constraints, you need to be pro if you still want to provide bottom constraints :)

Second approach ->
Use UITextView and disable user interaction. this one is simple and easy and not messy and more customizable.

Comment: for first approach you need to study about intrinsic size handling

Comment: If you're doing any UIKit development, understanding autolayout and intrinsic size is a basic you need to know about.

Comment: if you want to use UILabels please study content hugging and compression and priorities

Comment: I removed bottom constraints and it worked!. Thank you :)